# что лучше использовать для отступов в тексте: padding или margin

Tags: html, css

начал верстать статью, используя padding как отступ вниз и вверх, может лучше использовать margin?

Comment: Может лучше прочитать чем они отличаются и выбирать осознанно? Изначально у абзацев всегда был margin

Comment: я знаю чем они отличаются, но внешне нет никакой разницы